# Cropping the image - transparency

Tags: image, transparency, crop

Im trying to make the page with image cropping "frame". In the comment below is the jFiddle (although submit button isn´t working) .... What Im trying to do is that the part of the image, which is not in the crop frame, should be transparent, so the user could see, what part of the image is cropped. My googling led to nothing so far...:/ Can you help me how to do that transparency?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ztvyY/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another approach:

You need 2 divs one on top of each other, with same size. The div 1 will be "back" (z-index:-1) the div 2 will be on the "front" (z-index:1)

Div 1 will be the container of your image. With jquery, alter the div 1's background-image property giving specific x and y according with mouse movement.

Div 2 will be on top of that, and will have as background an image which has a square with correct dimensions, wich square will be transparent and surrounded by semi-transparent border. i made an image for your example :

[image: TRANSPARENT SQUARE WITH SEMI TRANSPARENT BORDER]

check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gTZQv/2/

you just need to initially "center" the background-image of div1 according to image dimensions example : background position of image will be (dont miss the minus "-" sign ;) )

```
backgroundX = -(loaded_image_width / 2) + (div1width/2) 
backgroundY = -(loaded_image_height / 2) + (div1height/2)
```

so css will be like (not actual code of course)

```
background:url('http://www.prelovac.com/vladimir/wp-content/uploads/2008/03/example.jpg') [backgroundX]px [backgroundY]px;
```

and via jquery you just change these values so image can be dragged with mouse

**UPDATE - CODE FOR YOU:**

this is a start:

http://jsfiddle.net/ztvyY/6/

Because i didnt want to re-write your code, i am using 3 divs, on top of each other, the first one has the image as background. the second one has the transparent border, and the third one is just an empty 1x1 transparent gif which i am using so your code will run and i am just passing the variables to reposition first divs background position. its a good start to play with. you just need to make sure to initialize the hardcoded numbers accordingly with your loaded image dimensions.

Comment: It seems it could be working but I can´t figure out, how to move the background with jQuery :(

Comment: @MichalSirůček i added some code, check it out, hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what your looking for...

[jquery image cropper](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2009/11/04/jquery-image-cropper-with-uploader-v1-1/)

Comment: Yes, that´s something I meant, but I should do that without plugins :(